# Make paragraph title look like (sub)section's one in Koma scrreprt

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, paragraphs, scrreprt

I'm writing a document in Koma-script using the class scrreprt. I'm using the `\paragraph{My paragraph's title}` command to set my "subsubsubsection" titles. However, Koma-script make these titles look weird : they're displayed at the place of the indent of the paragraph, just like so :

**My paragraph's title**   This is the content of my paragraph...

However, I want the title to look like the ones of section, subsection and subsubsection :

1.1.1.1.1.  My paragraph's title

To do so I use the command `\renewcommand*{\paragraphformat}{\hspace*{75pt}\makebox[60pt][l]{\theparagraph\autodot\hfil}}`. I use the same one for section etc. and it works fine for them but not for paragraph.

Can you help me with that please ?

Thanks !

Comment: Apparently I'm unable to say "Hi !" in my message, sorry for that bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must switch the runin option:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=false,afterskip=0pt,afterindent=false]{paragraph}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{abc}
\paragraph{paragraph}some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works pretty fine now.